# SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration(DTD) in wso2 ESB 4.9.0 when Calling an API

Tags: soap, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-esb

I try to call an identity server (for Reckon API), this will send back to me an HTML page which I should pass the username and password to it to authorise me but in WSO2 ESB the following message shows up:

> SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration(DTD)

I can see the html page details in the ESB log but.

```
Remaining input stream :[ &lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;script id=&#x27;modelJson&#x27; type=&#x27;application/json&#x27;&gt;{&quot;loginUrl&quot;:&quot;/login?signin=cdf07a3cb572cd62438b93ab5fa39b48&quot;,&quot;antiForgery&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;idsrv.xsrf&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Fws6qKgkCal2HVkpciKAuvce-95kVOdD5W2gJUSYzKivHJctKWRdpxoJDQmsJMS2kR7yI8cdRrDHKYafWGNY7-iiGlulWkqPBHF8rUoJXfg&quot;},&quot;allowRememberMe&quot;:true,&quot;rememberMe&quot;:false,&quot;username&quot;:null,&quot;externalProviders&quot;:[{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Microsoft&quot;,&quot;href&quot;:&quot;https://identity.reckon.com/external?provider=Microsoft&amp;signin=cdf07a3cb572cd62438b93ab5fa39b48&quot;},{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Google&quot;,&quot;href&quot;:&quot;https://identity.reckon.com/external?provider=Google&amp;signin=cdf07a3cb572cd62438b93ab5fa39b48&quot;}],&quot;additionalLinks&quot;:null,&quot;errorMessage&quot;:null,&quot;requestId&quot;:&quot;b07d58ce-9a48-448f-a665-31a40c08ae09&quot;,&quot;siteUrl&quot;:&quot;https://identity.reckon.com/&quot;,&quot;siteName&quot;:&quot;Reckon IdentityServer&quot;,&quot;currentUser&quot;:null,&quot;logoutUrl&quot;:&quot;https://identity.reckon.com/logout&quot;}&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script src="/assets/scripts.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt; ]
```

And 
Error:

```
org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil} - OMException in getSOAPBuilder org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createDTD(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:462) org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:282) org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204) org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154) org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140) org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:659) org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:206) org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:146) org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:109) org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:68) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:348) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:254) org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:175) org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:113) org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:85) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48) org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:175) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149) org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Did some one come a cross this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and posted it for other people like me. 
We should add content type text/javascript to the axis2 file. As you can see from the log the response is a javascript.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/javascript"
               class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="text/javascript"
                class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

Hope this would help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Enable message builder and formatter for conent-type text/xml(for html content) in /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

Message builder

```
 <messageBuilder contentType="text/html"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

Message formatter

```
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

Comment: Hi Jenananthan, Thank you for your response. I've tried to add them and restart ESB but still, it doesn't work. The same error:(